# Can't hide @Annotations suggestions from eclipse autocomplete function, Ctrl + Space

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

I have a boring problem in Eclipse, when I press Ctrl+Space next to an object looking for a methos Eclipse always shows me suggestions starting from Annotations and after this long annotations list i find the methods of the the class. How can I exclude annotations from suggestions? I gave many tries but nothing worked, always annotations there. Thanks in advance
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTh3Z.png)

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the current Eclipse instead of telling you have a boring problem that can be reproduced.

Comment: @howlger i uploaded an image to better explain, it's not a specific code issue. Just happens when pressing ctrl+ space always..

Comment: Please show a code snippet with which this can reproduced in the current Eclipse (in previous Eclipse versions there have been similar issues that have been fixed, but maybe it's something that have been overlooked).